# Setting up security for each src folder in Symfony

Tags: symfony, security, routes, bundle

I try to set up security per folder under src/ in Symfony. But I want a different set of security rules per main folder "General" and "Intranet" **without having to prefix the routes**... So I only have to prefix "Extranet"

Is that possible? I know that with a prefix in routing.yml it is very easy to do but that is not an option since the visible urls will suddenly change

The problem arises when we have to allow External users to our platform. For years it was only available for the companies' employees only but now external people must have access to certain pages. And some general routes (ajax calls etc) must be available for all

- src/

  - Intranet/ => Open routes for internal users

    - SomeBundle
    - ...
  - General/ => Open routes for all users

    - AnotherBundle
    - ...
  - Extranet/ => Open routes for external users

    - TheBestBundle
    - ...

Then the **Extranet** routes all get an extra prefix /extranet/. But I would like to have the other 2 (General and Intranet) **without any prefix**

```
# routing.yml
extranet:
    resource: "@ExtranetBundle/Controller/"
    prefix:   /extranet/
```

Then with access control I take care of the /extranet routes

```
access_control:
    # Login and the base_route "/" is always available
    - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # External users + Super admins + server IP's can only access urls starting with /extranet/
    - 
        path: ^/extranet/*
        roles: [ROLE_EXTERNAL_USER, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
        ips: !php/const:SomeBundle\SomeClass\ConstantProvider::ALLOWED_SERVER_IPS

    # Some routes need to be available for both internal and external users
    # but hopefully without having to prefix them

    ...

    # All other routes are only for internal users and the right ip addresses
    - 
        path: ^/*
        role: ROLE_INTERNAL_USER
        ips: !php/const:SomeBundle\SomeClass\ConstantProvider::ALLOWED_SERVER_IPS
```

Or maybe an idea of approaching this problem differently?

Comment: You could add an interface to all the internal controllers inside the general folder and then write a subscriber that checks the request and blocks all external users if the current controller implements the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the best approche is to use voter external user need to have a unique ROLE (EXTERNAL_ROLE) then you can use voter to deney resources you want to protect https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html so this way you can protect a resource based on a the logic not on the folder